# Best way to clean up mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I used the Boolean tools to subtract one mesh to another and thus create this mesh.

[image]

The result is not very clean. How can I do to best clean this result and get a nice smooth surface?

Do I need to re-arrange the vertex one by one, or is there a faster, simpler and more effective solution?

Comment: can you share the blend file.  There is a faster way, but it would be easier to explain on the actual blend file, one step at a time.

Comment: By the way, you can make of the problem disappear by turning on auto smooth in properties editor -> object data properties -> normals

Comment: @MartyFouts No sorry, i can't share the blend file!

Comment: @MartyFouts you can propose a solution, it's fixed with your solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to select the object, and go to properties editor -> object data properties -> normals and enable auto-smooth with an angle of 30 degrees or more:

[image: auto smooth enabled.].